# Different certificates for each REST-service installation

Tags: c#, rest, ssl, https, certificate

We are about to implement SSL for a .NET Framework product that uses a service layer which in turn uses NancyFX and REST/JSON.

The clients communicating with the service need to access it through HTTPS, hence the need for a certificate. We are running on both Windows and Linux (through Mono) and the user is prompted for a username/password or sending it through auth header.

To get the clients to trust the certificate, it must be assigned by a trusted CA but how do we solve this when we do not know anything about the address on which the service is configured?

So - how to get a trusted certificate assigned to the installed service with a minimum effort for the user. Best thing would be to handle this through a normal Install procedure (on Windows). Is this possible?

We have a large number of users (> 5000) that will go through the upgrade process and will be needing the certificate, so to manually create and assign certificates does not seem like an option.

Comment: Do you need to authenticate your clients with their own SSL (x509) Certificate or are you simply trying to ensure the data is encrypted?

Comment: I would like the certificate to be trusted so that connecting clients (not having a client certificate) does not get a warning when connecting. Self-signed "non-trusted" certificate would be a last resort...